# Rails 3 - automatically testing specified type of specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I develop Rails 3 app with Rspec. For automatically testing i use `autotest` gem which is great but... But project grows, i have more and more files and `autotest` has strange rules - sometimes it tests files which i previously changed, sometimes it tests whole project (and it takes a LOT of time). Do you know any useful gem which allows to test automatically in background + it lets you choose what exactly to test, for example, models specs, or only controllers, or integrations tests, or whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard will watch your spec files and project files and run the relevant specs (IE, run the model spec after changing that model), and has a good amount of customization

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec